How to find the mouse coordinates of a text drawn in any transformed space?


var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.setTransform(0.75, 0, -0, 0.75, 197.39999389648438, 129 )

ctx.fillText("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", 4, 5);
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>



How do I get the mouse coordinates of the first character in the text?
I tried to find the equivalent coordinate of above in identity matrix transform so it can be mapped with mouse coordinate but didn't work.

get canvas mouse coordinates after transformation using ctx.getTransformation()
